# Is there anything wrong with winning in a raffle a Rebbe dollar that someone received himself and is giving it away?

Tags: blessing, chassidic-rebbe

For example, if the Bracha for the rebbe dollar was let’s say for children- and in order for that person to have children they had to be poor- would that affect the person whose receiving this “blessed for children” dollar? And they get that Bracha too and become poor?

Comment: Why can't one give away an item they received? For that matter, Most likely the one giving away the dollar has more than one.

Answer (score 0):

The Rebbe's dollar blessings only "work" for the recipient if he performs a mitzva with that or a substitute dollar.  The dollar has no spiritual power.

Comment: [citation needed]

Answer (score 0):

There is no halacha being violated by doing so. If the owner is ok with giving away his or her own property and isn't being pressured to do so then the dollar is just like any other thing they own.

As far as any bracha potentially associated with the dollar? The dollar itself never had any connection to such any bracha rather it was the connection that was created by going to the Lubavitcher Rebbe to receive it and the resolution to perform a good dead especially tzedakah after receiving it. It would therefore be positive for someone who is given such a dollar to give tzedakah and make a resolution to take on some addition positive action in connection to Torah and mitzvos.